# Receipt images database

Tags: data-request, images

I am looking for a database of receipt images (like of receipts you get from the supermarket). I didn't found any open database, do any of you know something useful?

I would need a few thousand images at best, but less is still good.

Comment: Do you have access to a large company, which has a fair amount of business travel going on? If yes, check how they handle receipts. There is a large probability that receipts are scanned and stored for tax reasons.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not working in a big company, but thanks for the suggestion. I think it would actually take that long to collect them if many people are involved...

Comment: Relevant? [Expensify sent images with personal data to Mechanical Turkers, calls it a feature](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2017/11/expensify-acknowledges-potential-privacy-problem-by-calling-it-a-feature/)

Comment: @FrancescoPasa did you get any public dataset?

Comment: @sobingt Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 1):

You could try 'Neat Receipts'. It will do what you seem to be looking for. I have used it for a couple of years now because it is the only thing that I have found that will store scanned receipts and let me tag it with dates, amounts, taxes, vendor name and expense classification, without costing me a fortune. That being said, their support is painful and their software hangs often .. so it can be a bit of a frustrating experience.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! However, it looks like a software to read and classify receipts, am I wrong? I am looking for a dataset of tagged receipts (at least the amount). If i do not find one, I will have to do it myself :-P

Answer (score 0):

Check out the ICDAR 2019 Robust Reading Challenge on Scanned Receipts OCR and Information Extraction: https://rrc.cvc.uab.es/?ch=13

You have to make a free account and then you can access the dataset, approximately 1000 images of scanned receipts.